# File ended whilst scanning use of \@writefile... also Goto Error just takes me to \begin{document}

Tags: errors, braces

This may be a basic question, but I have been using LaTeX on and off for many years and am used to finding missing braces, I have tries %'ing out my document but still cannot find an error?

Are there any other methods of identifying problems... I tend to run the document regularly so usually can pick up an error based on what I have recently done, but I'm stumped

Thanks in advance

Comment: that error is almost always a corrupted aux file (which is input at begin document)  so first thing is to delete the aux file and re-run. (Usual reason for aux file being corrupt is killing the job after an error, rather than allowing tex to cleanup with `x`)

Comment: lots of examples of that error: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=use+of+%5C%40writefile